# IP address based authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, authorization, spring-rest

I'm developing a simple Spring Boot RESTful API for poll management. In a few words, it's possible to create public polls and other "users" can vote for it.

Now I've to make sure that each client just votes once per poll. Because I want to prevent using common authentication mechanisms like `HTTP Basic` or `JWT`, I thought about authorizing by clients IP address. Means I store en entity like the following in database:

```
public class Vote {

    private Long pollId;
    private Long choiceId;
    private String ipAddress;

    ...
}
```

Using something like such an approach, I prevent the need of authentication and account management.

Is this the right approach or are there better ones to ensure each client votes just once? Also how to deal with IP spoofing? Hope for any recommendations.

Comment: When a device is connected to the internet, each time it is assigned a different IP address (unless using a static IP). You should use something like MAC address etc instead.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz And how do you propose we get the client's MAC address?

Comment: @Malt well, we can't extract it from the request. I am just proposing that something like a MAC address should be used instead of an IP address.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz That's like proposing we use the client's CPU serial number. There's no way of getting either of those things.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Also, MAC addresses aren't always unique. A classic example is network interfaces of virtual machines.

Comment: @Malt Yes, you're right, they aren't always unique. But there got to be something unique... Something like fingerprinting (but that would be specific to the web browser. Chrome, Firefox etc would have a different fingerprint).

Comment: You could also set a cookie, which on its own also isn't foolproof, but it stops *casual* double voting. Are users not identified in any way (e.g. logged in previously with a username)?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul cookie would be specific to a web browser. If the user tries to vote from a different browser (or from the incognito window) he will again be treated as a new user. No?

Comment: Like I said, not foolproof on its own, but the vast majority of (good faith) users mainly use their one main browser anyway. The only way to be foolproof is to authenticate users and store the vote against their account. Even then what's to stop them from opening another? And if you're using IP address, you might not even get a unique one for mobile device users, possibly depending on their network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the right approach or are there better ones to ensure each
>   client votes just once?

Not really. The idea that each computer has a unique IP address is only partially true.

In reality, people have more than one device (e.g. phone, computer at work, computer at home). And each device could be connected to a different network, with a unique IP in each one. Also, IP address change quite frequently. Disconnect your home modem/router for a couple of minutes and you're likely to get a new IP address when it reconnects. So one can change his home IP and vote again. Moreover, many (if not most) clients are behind [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) devices, which means that their IP is shared with many other users. Under the scheme you propose, once someone behind the same NAT as you votes, no one else can.
Lastly, users can easily use VPNs, TOR and various other techniques to basically vote as many times as they want.

> Also how to deal with IP spoofing?

IP address spoofing is not trivial if one is using TCP. However, getting an actual IP address that's different from your current one is quite easy (VPNs, TOR, etc), and there's little you can do about it.

Comment: Do you have another approach for authentication without user accounts?

Comment: Something foolproof? No. But you could use additional information, not just the IP address. For instance, a phone number which is much harder to change quickly. You could also use browser fingerprinting techniques to try to identify the same computer coming back a second time.